# php Undefined variable canonical error

Tags: php, apache

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: canonical

Filename: views/header.php

Line Number: 19


 <? if(isset($canonical) && $canonical) { ?>
    <link rel="canonical" href="<?= $canonical ?>" />
  <? } ?>
```

Is there setting in php.ini I need to turn on to fix the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: @aioobe the linked question doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let me warn you that you are using `short open tag` for coding, which is not good practice.Please try this:-

issue is in your condition also and in your link code also,So try this:-

```
 <?php if(isset($canonical) && !empty($canonical)) { ?>
    echo "<link rel="canonical" href=" .$canonical ." />";
  <?php  } ?>
```

Note:- Why i tell like above because it's ok that you have enabled setting for `short open tag` but on other system if they are not enabled it will not work.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to address the issue rather than suppress the warning message.

The issue is this line:

```
if(isset($canonical) && $canonical)
```

The use of `isset($canonical)` is fine, however you're directly using the same variable in the same scope, which is causing the message.

Change it to this:

```
<?php if( isset( $canonical ) ): ?>
    <link rel="canonical" href="<?= $canonical ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

You don't need the extra `&& $canonical` assuming that you don't have code that would ever initialize the `$canonical` variable to a null or empty state.

Other tips:
1. Use `<?php` instead of the `<?` "short tags" because of symbol conflicts with XML declarations. I understand by default newer versions of PHP have short-tags disabled. Note that the `<?= ?>` shorthand (for `echo`) is always permitted.
2. Use the `if: endif;` syntax to make page rendering code easier to follow.

Comment: @Rizier123 That link doesn't have `E_NOTICE` enabled.

Comment: In php if the first logical comparison for `&&` matches as true any future comparisons aren't evaluated. Your assumption of using the same variable withing the same "scope" seems incorrect.

Comment: @Luceos I know the `&&` operator is short-circuiting, but given the voodoo that PHP employs when interpreting and evaluating code it could be raised before then.